# DELETE approach in Large in ORACLE TABLE

Tags: oracle

Hi can anyone help me with bellow question:
"Let’s say, you have table 100 million record, you want delete 16 million record, what would be your better approach?"

Comment: under what constraints? quickly? minimal interruptions? does it need to be done in one transaction? are there any indexes on the table? are we allowed to drop and recreate indexes? How long can the table be offline? Is the table being used?

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot use partitioning I remember this old trick:

1. create new_table as select

   create table new_table unrecoverable as 
   select * from old_table
   where
2. drop old_table
3. rename new_table to old_table
4. recreate all necessary indexes

   create index old_table_idx1 on old_table(c1,c2) unrecoverable parallel 5;

see the discussion on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689) site

Comment: ... and recreate triggers, constraints, privileges, materialised view logs, materialised views, backup new table and indexes (hoping for no failure that causes data loss before that's complete), recompile dependent code ...

Comment: the best scenario is `partition the data so that you can do a DROP partition instead of DELETE` but when we cannot use partitioning we need  find work around.

Comment: yes, but the trouble is that although in simple cases the "CTAS/drop/rename" method is convenient for performance reasons, there are many caveats that mean that it can need very detailed planning, testing, risk mitigation (temporary lack of backups), and testing. I'd do it on a development database, but if it were for example a production Siebel system I'd be really, really cautious about this approach.